# How to loop over folders and skip one

Tags: python

I have this code below, I want to skip "NetIQ" folder in my iteration, but I think I'm missing something there because I still get files from that folder when I run my code, please help.

```
path = "C:\User\Work\Identity\TestFolders"

def list_files(dir):
    r = []
    skip = ["NetIQ"]
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        if dirs in skip:
            continue
        else:
            for name in files:
                r.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return r

print(list_files(path))
```

Comment: Do a simple debugging: print out the used variables before the `if`.

Comment: @user2738776 When referring to file paths in python, you are not supposed to use one backslash. If you use, you will probably get `Syntax Error`. You should actually use one forward slash or double backslash.

Comment: To do what you're thinking, you want to be testing against `root` rather than `dirs`.  Beware - `root` is a full path - For each iteration you're processing the directory indicated by `root`.  `dirs` is a list of directories in that directory.  `files` is a list of files in that directory.  Your code is saying "don't process the files in this directory if it also contains a directory named "NetIQ".  I don't think that's what you want.  If you want to prevent traversal into "NetIQ", then you want to remove it from `dirs` when you find it there.  That's what @Wasif's answer is getting at.

Answer (score 0):

Try out a list comprehension:

```
def list_files(dir):
    r = []
    skip = ["NetIQ"]
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(dir):
        dirs[:] = [d for d in dirs if d not in skip]
        for name in files:
          r.append(os.path.join(root, name))

    return r

print(list_files(path))
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation of what's going on here?  Code-only answers are discouraged in general. I think here, it's especially confusing for you not to explain what is going on here and why it differs significantly from what the OP was trying to do.

Comment: @Steve hi, it does what because `dirs` is not a string

Answer (score 0):

I think your expectation of the output of this `for` loop is wrong. `os.walk` does a depth first search through your directories and will yield a new output (`root`, `dirs` and `files`) for every subdirectory. So if you say

```
if dirs in skip:
    continue
```

This will only apply for the directory where `NetIQ` is actually located - check, the files in this folder should be missing.

For a solution, see the other answers...

Answer (score 0):

I had similar problem and came with a similar solution:
(traverse *.py files, skipping some folders):

```
def list_files(dir):
    r = []
    skip = ["bin", "venv"]
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(str(dir)):
        if any(skip_dir in dirs for skip_dir in skip):
            continue
        else:
            for name in files:
                r.append(os.path.join(root, name))
    return r
```